# How to create a PHP dropdown list that allows you to select multiple options?

Tags: php

This is the basis for the code I'm using, drawing options from a database but no matter how I alter this code I will only let me select 1 option or return an error.

```
<select name="sargentid" id="fieldsargentid" class="form-control">          

<?php foreach ($sargent as $sargent) { echo "<option value='" . $sargent->getID() . 
"'>$sargent</option>"; }?>

</select>
```

Comment: If you want to select multiple options, then you can set multiple="true" in your select tag in HTML.

Comment: And besides adding `multiple`, you will need to modify the field name as well. It has to be something like `name="sargentid[]"`, so that PHP will create an _array_ of the submitted values; otherwise it will just overwrite all the values with the last one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose more than one option from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524462/how-to-choose-more-than-one-option-from-a-select-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="sargentid" id="fieldsargentid" class="form-control" multiple=multiple>
    <?php

    foreach($sargent as $sargentKey => $sargentList){ 
      $values = $sargentList['NameofTheRowInTable'];
      ?>
        <options value = <?php echo $values; ?> ><?php echo $values;?></options>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The question is to select Multiple options in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

A drop-down list that allows multiple selections using the `multiple` attribute:

```
<select id="animals" name="animal" multiple>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="mouse">Mouse</option>
  <option value="lion">Lion</option>
</select>
```

Hold down the `Ctrl` (windows) / `Command` (Mac) button to select multiple options.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/prk6c9q7/

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name="sargentid" id="fieldsargentid" class="form-control" multiple>          
<? foreach($argent as $data){?>
<option value="<?=$data->getID() ?>"><?= $data ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Try This

Comment: can you explain.

Comment: yes, i used foreach with $argent variable of php which is associative array , it will iterate with all value and echo value. <?= $argent->getID() ?> is similar as <? echo $argent ?>

Comment: the question is to select multiple values from the select box, not about populating the dropdown from database.

Comment: add multiple in select tag